# Select a single field from a foreign key

Tags: django

So I have a a very simple (simplified) model

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    owning_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

Now in one of my templates I'm trying to iterate over a list of these objects to determine whether something should be displayed similar to this

```
{% for my_object in foo.my_object_set %}
    {% if my_object.owning_user.id == user.id %}
         Show Me!
    {% endif %}
```

This works fine, but what I am finding is that the query

```
my_object.owning_user.id
```

returns every field from the owning user before getting the id which is verified both in django debug tool bar, and checking the connection queries

```
# django-debug-toolbar states this is repeated multiple times     
SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1

# The following test code also confirms this
from django.db import connection
conn = connection
bearing_type.owning_user.id
print conn.queries[-1]
```

Now since this query repeats over 1000 times and takes 2ms per query it is taking 2 seconds just to perform this - when all I care about is the id...

Is there anyway at all that I can just perform a query to get just the id from the `owning_user` instead of having to query all the fields?

<sub>Note, I'm trying really hard here to avoid making a raw query</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `my_object.owning_user_id` instead of `my_object.owning_user`, then Django will use the id instead of looking up the user.

In this case, you only need the id, but if you needed other user attributes, you could use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). In the view, you would do:

```
foo.my_object_set.select_related('user')
```

In the template, you don't have as much control, since you can't pass arguments.

```
{{ foo.my_object_set.select_related }}
```

Comment: Oh wow, theres days where I just love django... Thanks! In reference to your addition, I knew about select_related but being crippled by the template side of things removed that for me, nor did I think I really needed it since I dont want logic in there too much :)