# Django - iterating a queryset produces hundreds of queries

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model where a "variable template" is defined, and attached to every Location model in the database, producing a 2-dimensional array of instances of these variables.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False, unique=True)

class LocationVariableDefinition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="text")
    default_value = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, default="[UNSET]")

class LocationBasedVariable(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    definition = models.ForeignKey(LocationVariableDefinition, default=None)

    value = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
```

To edit these variables, I have a single page with a table, variable names down the side, and locations along the top. I added a new SimpleTag to allow me to access values from a dict-within-a-dict, and the view produces this dict:

```
class VarListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "lbv-list.html"

    def locations(self):
        return Location.objects.all()

    def locvars(self):

        dict = {}

        for v in LocationBasedVariable.objects.all():
            dict.setdefault(v.location.id, {})
            dict[v.location.id][v.definition.id] = v.value

        return dict

    def locvarnames(self):
        return LocationVariableDefinition.objects.all()
```

and then in the template:

```
    <table class="table  table-striped table-condensed    striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            {% for loc in view.locations %}
                <th>{{ loc.name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for lv in view.locvarnames %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ lv.name }}</th>
                {% for loc in view.locations %}
                    <td>{% get_dictitem2 view.locvars loc.id lv.id%}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Which all works, except that with 3 locations and 5 variables, I get **475** SQL queries, taking about 3 seconds to run on my laptop.

What can I do to improve this? I always thought that the queryset would be cached, but the SQL logged in the console seems to be fetching the same sets over and over. Is there a hint I can give Django that the result won't have changed, or a way to do each query only once?

Or should I be just passing a sorted queryset to the template, and figuring out the rows and columns in there? (the way I would normally do that would involve keeping state in the template for the last location to compare with the current, and I don't think I can do that in a template)

Comment: You can start to reduce the queries by changing `.id` to `_id`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32869856/1324033) for an example..

Comment: I'd imagine the three answers given below combined should drastically reduce your amount of queries and execution time..

Comment: @Sayse - agreed! I think the real key is that I'd somehow thought that the view.locvars() would only get evaluated once. I'll go back to actually creating a context and adding to it instead, which is what I would normally have done, except I found this neat blog article yesterday...

Comment: I think that is the best place to start, I'd be curious to see just how many of those 475 you are able to remove

Comment: Hehe - by putting get_context_data back in, and also switching from location.id to location_id (and for varname), I now get 6 queries in 29ms... 100x faster! Thanks for the pointers, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach would be to evaluate the methods once, and add the results to the template context in `get_context_data`.

```
class VarListView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(VarListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['locations'] = self.locations()
        context['locvarnames'] = self.locavarnames()
        context['locvars'] = self.locvars()
        return context
```

Then, in your template, remove the `view` prefix e.g. `locations` instead of `view.locations`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here, but I think the best is to use the `_id` property for your foreign key relations. Django stores the id of the foreign keys on the model in question, so in your case you could replace your loop with:

```
for v in LocationBasedVariable.objects.all():
    dict.setdefault(v.location_id, {})
    dict[v.location_id][v.definition_id] = v.value
```

This means that you won't have to query the related tables just to get the ID.

Also, it looks like you are invoking `{% get_dictitem2 view.locvars loc.id lv.id%}` for each item in `view.locvarnames` which in turn will go to the database, load all of your LocationBasedVariable and populate that dict.

I might be tempted to cache that in the view so you only populate it once:

```
class VarListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "lbv-list.html"
    _location_based_variable_cache = None

    def locations(self):
        return Location.objects.all()

    def locvars(self):

        if not self._location_based_variable_cache:
            self._location_based_variable_cache = {}

            for v in LocationBasedVariable.objects.all():
                self._location_based_variable_cache.setdefault(v.location_id, {})
                self._location_based_variable_cache[v.location_id][v.definition_id] = v.value

        return self._location_based_variable_cache

    def locvarnames(self):
        return LocationVariableDefinition.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from changing `.id` to `_id`, you should also be looking at what you actually need to return, since your for loop only ever uses the id you could just use `values` to filter this to start with

```
query_gives_locations.values('id')
```

You have to keep getting `.locvars` every time so you can move this outside with `with`

```
{% with locvars=view.locvars %}
{% for loc in view.locations %}
        <td>{% get_dictitem2 locvars loc_id lv_id%}</td>

{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```