# Which is better? city.state.id or city.state_id

Tags: django

I have to table with relation.

## State

- id
- name

## City

- id
- name
- state

Which is better in performance?

`city.state.id` or `city.state_id`

Comment: Have you tried making a benchmark? Has state been accessed before?

Comment: @Sayse No dude. I don't know how can I make benchmark! and state has not been accessed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`city.state_id` is better anyway. `city.state` will do another fetch from database.You can avoid this using `select_related`.If you need only `id` of foriegn key, no need of `select_related` here.Just do `city.state_id`(since foriegn key id will fetch in the query which gives `city` object).

Answer (score 1):

`city.state_id` is better than `city.state.id`. Because It makes only a query instead of two.

BTW, You can use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for debugging queries.

Answer (score 1):

the `<field>_id` field you see is the database column name

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column

So this means it doesn't need to make a separate query to retrieve the foreign key instance (See [Select a single field from a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869856/select-a-single-field-from-a-foreign-key) for more details).

But this assumes you haven't used `select_related` or `prefetch_related`

Comment: what is `select_related` difference in this case?

Comment: ["....means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)