# How to optimize this specific Queryset?

Tags: django

In a Django application, I have a set of companies with a history of actions that have been performed in the past. I retrieve those transactions with the following, scandalously expensive Queryset:

```
class Company(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    def get_transactions_history(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(sponsorship__campaign__shop__company=self)
```

Obviously, this leads to a lot of `JOIN` instructions from the ORM and since the number of `Transactions` can increase rapidly, the throughput on the db is also exploding because of this Queryset.

Assuming there is no shortcut between `Transaction` and `Company` other than chaining through `Sponsorship`, `Campaign` and `Shop` as exposed above, how would you optimize the Queryset without touching at the database schema?

Comment: If the end result of transaction - company relationship is like a "passthrough", using a "trigger" to create a shadow copy of just "transaction_id" and "company_id" whenever a transaction is created seems logical to me

Comment: The only thing close to an optimization would be `shop__company_id=self.id` but I don't think that would help much

Comment: @Sayse how would `company_id=self.id` improve the performance? Is it because comparing two integers is faster than comparing two objects?

Comment: @Buddyshot - [Select a single field from a foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32869856/1324033). When accessing the field normally it would need to retrieve the whole object, but I don't think the same applies during a filter (I haven't checked it lately)

Comment: Can you post simplified versions of all the models involved

Comment: Is your issue that you are running this query multiple times on one page load or that just one instance of this query takes a long time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really can but you can be smarter with how you use it.

Theres [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)

```
@cached_property
def history(self):
```

Which does exactly what it says it is.

Otherwise you need to split this into a `recent_history` that splices the queryset

```
.filter(...)[:10]
```

or pagination

Answer (score 0):

If you can't optimize it at the SQL level then there's not much you can do at the ORM level, obviously.