# Django ORM "." vs "_" when access the id of foreign key

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author= models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Consider those two models. When I access this foreign key, what's the difference between those two ways:

```
id= Book.objects.get(pk=1).author.id
id= Book.objects.get(pk=1).author_id
```

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) - [Select a single field from a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32869856/1324033)

If you check out the query that `author.id` produces, you'll see that it fetches the entire author model unnecessarily

Answer (score 12):

**Semantically** there is *no difference*. But the version with `author_id` will be **more efficient** than `author.id`.

If you define a foreign key, then you actually defined two Django fields at once: the `fieldname`, which is a reference to a model object to the model to which you refer, and a field `fieldname_id`, that contains the value of the primary key to the object to which you refer. Only the latter is stored in the database (since the former *can* usually not be stored in a database).

Note that if you want to access the `.author`, usually this means that you have to perform an *extra* query, since those relations, unless explicitly loaded with `.select_related(..)`, are not loaded immediately, but *lazily*: it requires an extra database to obtain the relevant `Author` object. Of course one extra query does not matter that much, but if you would for example do this in a `for` loop, then this results in the *n+1*-problem: you will need 1 query to fetch the books, and *n* queries to fetch the author of every book.

Note that there are - as mentioned before - ways to reduce the amount of querying for related objects with `prefetch_related`, and `select_related`. But still it will result in transferring more data. If you are *only* interested in the *primary key* of the `Author`, then you can use `author_id`, which does not require such extra fetch.

Comment: The field "id" is the only field can enjoy syntax this advantage?

Comment: @TianchengLiu: well the primary key (you can have another primary key than `id`), since this is stored *in the table* of `Book`s.

Comment: Thx, I know. If using ".”,  django is going to query author table, if using "_", it's just a field in book table.